# JCombBox во главе столбца JTable

Tags: java, swing

Как сделать, чтобы во главе каждого столбца у меня был JComboBox? И при выборе пункта из списка у меня показывались только те строки таблицы, в которых присутствует выбранный пункт(сортировка таблицы)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Например, на скриншоте во главе колонки таблицы стоит "Тип заявки". На него можно нажать и выбрать тип, и будут показываться строки таблицы только с таким типом

Comment: вы про фильтр наверное?

Comment: это сразу 2 вопроса =)

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/EditableHeaderTableExample2.htm